# Remove special error characters in Web pages when paring

Tags: parsing, character

I have a web page with text like "Alexander Macomb, Junior (3 April 1782 鈥� 25 June 1841) was the commanding general of the United States Army from 29 May 1828 to 25 June 1841.".

These characters (鈥�?) are presented wrongly in the web page already. By the way, these characters (鈥�?) seem to be "-". How can I remove/correct such characters. I mean, is there any way to detect and correct such characters when reading/loading the web page content to java or other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This is a character encoding problem: some software has performed incorrect character code conversions. Without more details about the situation, like a URL, it is hardly possible to suggest specific remedies. But the page appears to be some distorted copy of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Macomb_%28general%29 so maybe you can use that page. The distortion apparently consists of munging the EN DASH “–” U-2013 character somehow.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Maybe I should find the original web page and parse it from there.